# rowsums accross specific row in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, rowsum

```
final.marks
#          raj sanga rohan rahul
#physics    45    43    44    49
#chemistry  47    45    48    47
#total      92    88    92    96
```

This is the matrix I have. Now I want to find the total for each subject separately across respective subject rows and add them as a new column to the above matrix as the 5th column . However my code i.e  `class.marks.chemistry<- rowSums(final.marks[2,])` keeps producing an error saying

> Error saying
>   rowSums(final.marks[2, ]) : 
>     'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Can you please help me solve it. I am very new to R or any form of scripting or programming background.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
# Sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "          raj sanga rohan rahul
physics    45    43    44    49
chemistry  47    45    48    47
total      92    88    92    96", header  = T)

# Add column total with row sum
df$total <- rowSums(df);
df;
#          raj sanga rohan rahul total
#physics    45    43    44    49   181
#chemistry  47    45    48    47   187
#total      92    88    92    96   368
```

The above also works if `df` is a `matrix` instead of a `data.frame`.

---

If you look at `?rowSums` you can see that the `x` argument needs to be

> an array of two or more dimensions, containing numeric,
>             complex, integer or logical values, or a numeric data frame.

So in your case we must pass the entire `data.frame` (or `matrix`) as an argument, rather than a specific column (like you did).

Comment: oh thanks a lot just a question what if i have to extract the rowsum of a subject as a new variable without creating a new column in the main matrix ?

Comment: Just do `new_var <- rowSums(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `addmargins` on a `matrix`

```
addmargins(as.matrix(df), 2)
#         raj sanga rohan rahul Sum
#physics    45    43    44    49 181
#chemistry  47    45    48    47 187
#total      92    88    92    96 368
```